# Apache 2 server on ubuntu can't parse php code inside html file

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I installed apache2, php5 and the php5 apache module on Ubuntu 13.04.

Php is working on .php files but lines of php code inside html files do not execute.

Googling I found that must add  `AddHandler...` and `AddType...` lines to httpd.conf but the version installed doesn't have this file or at least can't find it in `/etc/apache2/`

code example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php 
      phpinfo(); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously if you cannot find those lines that Google is telling you to add, then you add them, restart Apache, and test again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php

Comment: @HalfCrazed i said i cannot find the _file_ httpd.conf not the lines. thanks for the reference

Comment: I'm new here. why negative votes?

Comment: In your server, you can try `locate httpd.conf` to get paths to the file I believe.

Comment: Also, your server might be setup to use `httpd-vhosts.conf` config file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it to work. my version of apache doesn't have httpd.conf, instead has `php5.conf` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`

editing that file, found this:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler applicatio
    ....
....
```

added the lines:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

now php parses the html files and `<?php ... ?>` code works.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably check under /etc/conf/httpd/httpd.conf

Alternatively you may want to use the 'find' command or run 'updatedb' and then 'locate httpd.conf' file.

The issue is unless you add the correct directives in httpd.conf - your php file will be rendered as a plain text file. Hence you wil have to LoadModule && AddType to get it running.

Comment: tried looking for that path but no luck. 'locate httpd.conf' get me no file. i already find the solution, will post it as soon as i can.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use a .htaccess configuration file for this.

Create a blank text file and name it **.htaccess**

(If your operating system does not allow file names starting with a dot just name the file **temp.htaccess** temporarily. After you have uploaded it to your server, rename the file to **.htaccess**)

Add the following line into the file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

If this does not work, try changing it to:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

This is assuming that your apache configuration allows for .htaccess files to override the default settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it's solved already. had to add some lines to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`. will post details soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf

    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

this worked for me. 
Thx
Lukjar