# HTTP response is entire PHP file

Tags: php, http, ionic-framework

In my ionic app I have an $http.post() that sends user information to my PHP file. The PHP file then calls a proc to store the information in MySQL and echos the success. The problem I'm seeing however is when I log the response to the console, the entire PHP file is printed instead of 1/0, from success. I found that instead of running the PHP file, it just seems to be printed to the log. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think After doing all the stuff in php file you are not returning anything. try to return 1 or 0 based on success or failure and then check. Also put exit after return value.

Comment: That's actually what I have but the entire file is being returned as the response instead of running it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the handler for `.php` on the server.

In your .htaccess or httpd.conf add this handler.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find the httpd.conf on ubuntu. Would I just add the line to etc/apache2.conf?

Comment: Sorry, not a Linux expert.  Same thing happened to me years ago.  I do believe on Ubuntu that is the correct conf file.  You should see similar statements in that file.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Good reason not to put passwords in your PHP. I use includes to a file in a non-public directory just for that reason.  
A simple misconfig and your passwords are exposed.

Comment: Yea I completely agree lol but unfortunately when I added the line the problem is still occurring. I've been fighting with the thing for a while now.

Comment: You can do it by creating an .htaccess file in the same folder as the script like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495382/apache-2-server-on-ubuntu-cant-parse-php-code-inside-html-file

Comment: When I create the file would I need to include the AddHandler line in addition to `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`? Because I tried creating the file as instructed but with no avail

Comment: NO!  That is for someone that wants to make their PHP work with an .htm or .html extension.  They don't want users to know it is PHP.  Only the one line: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php`

Comment: You can try `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php`

Comment: Or I can let you put your stuff on my Shared Server.  I can create an account for you.

Comment: Though I would really appreciate that, I can't just because I'm working with someone else's system/database. And sorry about before, I tried changing the .htaccess file to the correct line but the php is still being printed. I'm starting to think there might be a problem with my lamp installation..

Comment: It's not supposed to be this difficult.   A lot of the times when something like this happens, it is some small stupid detail that was over looked.

Comment: Well I have the.htaccess file in my script directory which is inside the public_html. I took out the changes in apache2.conf. Maybe it's an issue with CORS when I use ionic serve? I have a CORS extension on my chrome browser and I have to include http://localhost:8100 to the url's or else I get an XMLHTTPRequest error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76794/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-get-otter-here).

Comment: sure! I'll join in a sec