# Laravel – Include external Project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In a Laravel project I have to include multiple projects, so that they are accessible at /example.
These projects have the structure of

```
/example
 - index.php
 - main.css
 - app.js

(Usually there are more files then that.)
```

I have tried to use `Redirect::to("example/index.php")`, however this breaks all the `<link>`'s & `<src>` (where I would need to prepend `/example` to all of them.

This would theoretically work, however I would rather not store these files in the Laravel project itself, since they are basically self-contained projects.

What is the best way to include such external projects?

Comment: Are the <link>s relative?

Comment: Yes, they are relative

Comment: Create a virtual host for each project, then they can be stored wherever you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtual hosts – are you referring to exanple.domain.com?

Comment: @Elwin - what webserver are you using? Nginx, Apache?

Comment: @Kyle O'Brien I'm using Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This would theoretically work, however I would rather not store these files in the Laravel project itself, since they are basically self-contained projects.

That's an excellent approach. Rather keep Laravel as Laravel and host the stuff just outside of your Laravel project.

Since you're using Apache, here's how to create a Virtual Host for that external project.

Please note - I'm assuming that your project lives in `/var/www`.

1. Decide on a URL for that project - I would use `example.mylaravelproject.com`. But anything will do.
2. Confirm the path of your project folder. For this example, we'll assume it's `/var/www/example/`
3. Run the following command (assuming you're using Ubuntu) - `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.mylaravelproject.com.conf`
4. Ensure the new file has the following contents:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <your email address here>
    ServerName example.mylaravelproject.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

5. Save and close the file
6. Run the following command `sudo a2ensite example.mylaravelproject.com.conf`
7. Run `sudo nano /etc/apache2.conf`
8. Make sure that this line appears somewhere in this file (preferrably in a `<Directory>` tag - `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`
9. Then restart Apache by issuing the following command `sudo service apache2 restart`

Technically now your site has a valid vhost and should be working.

If you're doing this on a local environment and want to access your example project via the browser, you'll need to complete a few more steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/hosts` - again, assuming that you're running Ubuntu
2. Add this line somewhere to your project: `localhost example.mylaravelproject.com`
3. Save and close that file. You should now be able to access that url via your browser.

If these steps don't work, it's likely that Apache isn't parsing the PHP files. If that's the case, try these links for some good answers on making Apache parse PHP:

- [Apache 2 server on ubuntu can't parse php code inside html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495382/apache-2-server-on-ubuntu-cant-parse-php-code-inside-html-file)
- [Apache Virtual Host not parsing PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php)