# form variables not passing to php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form and I'm trying to pass the form variable to php and output the value. I have tried to solve this myself with the almighty google but wasn't successful. The html form code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="test1.php">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the php to handle the form is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

        echo "<h1>Hello " . $_POST["username"] . "</h1>";

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output I'm getting no matter what I type into the html form is , Hello " . $_POST["username"] . ""; ?>

I don't know why it also outputs the ending semi colon and ending php tag also, maybe this is evidence of what's going wrong here?

Comment: Seems like your PHP is not working... did you check if it's running? Try creating a php file, and put the following line in it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Terry, <?php phpinfo(); ?> did work, any other suggestions?

Comment: Your form POSTs to "test1.php", are you sure you are editing the correct file?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that is the correct file

Comment: OK so can you format properly the output you get on submit. It is weird that `<h1>` is not output.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is

- misconfigured or
- not configured or
- not working or
- not working within HTML files.

You have to configure your webserver that it parses PHP inside HTML files, see here for example:

=> [Server not parsing .html as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)

Answer (score -3):

The syntax is fine, try to write a sample code snippet like below

```
<?
$a = "hello word!";
echo $a;
?>
```

and check if php is working.