# Login Verification , $_GET['id'] in php not working

Tags: php, authentication, get

THIS is the PHP code m using for checking the values

```
if($uname==$row['username']) {

    if($uname=='' || $pass=='') {       

        header("Location:login.html?id=Some fields are empty");

    } else if($uname==$row['username'] && $pass==$row['password']) {

        header("Location:1.html?id=$uname");

    } else {   

        // **HERE I AM REDIRECTING TO THE LOGIN PAGE AND SENDING ERROR MESSAGE AS ID**
        header("Location:login.html?id=Incorrect Password");    
    }       
}
```

In the HTML part I included this to show the error message

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
     echo $_GET['id'];
}
?>
```

However NOTHING is getting printed

Comment: Make sure your server is set to parse HTML as PHP... CHeck out the source, of the page served, I'm sure you can see the PHP in plain.

Comment: Do a `view source`. you'll see your PHP code in the browser, because you're serving it up as a `.html` file, which is generally NOT processed by PHP on the server. Rename to `.php`, update you forms, and try again.

Comment: Am I being naive, or don't you have to have php inside .php files?

Comment: @Aleski: PHP is not necessarily limited to *.php files

Comment: Unless you specifically tell the server to treat html files as php in the httpd.conf or .htaccess

Comment: OMG thank you soooo much!!! i cant believe it was that silly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, make sure that the server is set to parse .html file as PHP. See [Server not parsing .html as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)

The other option is to change your login.html to be login.php and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php filters  to check correctly if the values are set or not like the following :

```
filter_has_var(INPUT_GET , 'id');
```

this function returns true or false