# HeaderName in .htaccess do not uses .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have assigned *HeaderName path/.../head.html* in .htaccess,in which my php page (as it is set in action tag  in a form at head.html) is sending output from html to another page (that's obvious), and to display output on the same page, I must build my php code with html on the same page, and save it as .php extension, but HeaderName in .htaccess is not accepting .php extension,
also I am **strictly not allowed** to use *superglobal variables* (like SESSION) !! 
please help,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you use `.php` fine in `HeaderName` directive:

```
AddType text/html .php
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php
HeaderName /includes/header.php
```

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava: check this question for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php

Comment: Also elaborate what is not working? Do you understand: `** HeaderName **: Name of the file that will be inserted at the top of the index listing`

Comment: Dhanyawaad Shivanshu. Is this you: https://www.facebook.com/shivanshu.srivastava25?fref=ts ?