# Why is this PHP code showing up as regular text (html)?

Tags: php, html

I've been staring at this for almost an hour and as a last resort I was hoping some of you guys might give me a hand figuring out this php code is showing up as regular text in my html file? All help greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/YyH27/

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From:'; 
        $to = ''; 
        $subject = 'Hello';
        $human = $_POST['human'];

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: JSfiddle, really, really?

Comment: Try changing the extension to .php, some servers are configured not to pass anything to fastcgi unless it ends with .php and it's in a certain path. It's a safer practice than forwarding anything to the php interpreter.

Comment: JSFiddle is for javascript, won't run php at all, your code seems correct to me so i'm pretty sure your server not being setup properly, what server is it (Mac, Windows, ubuntu, CentOS, etc..) ? did you install php on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I really only see two possibilities:

a) You are not running it on a server, but on your local PC. If that is the case and you don't have acces to websapce, look at WAMP (windows) or MAMP (Mac)

b) You have a .html-file-extension instead of .php

If it's neither of these, give us more information about where you're runnng the script, how it's saved and everything. Php should never show up as plain text because of an error inside the php - merley because of errors surrounding the php.

Comment: If I have php inside my html file do I need to rename the file to .php instead of .html?

Comment: Yes. If the file extension is not .php then the server will not process it as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First off, jsfiddle will not run PHP.

Second, it sounds like your PHP server is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a `.html` file, you need to configure your webserver to [run html through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php).

If you're expecting JSFiddle to run your PHP, they do not do that.