# Contact form redirect to index.php page shows up with code in the page

Tags: php, html

I have found this code for redirecting my contact form through an index.php page, but               it shows up with part of the code on the redirect page.  The code looks okay to me, I don't know what I am missing.  Here  it is:

```
<html>
<head>



<style type= "text/css">
   body {
    background-color: #C2C2FF;
  } 

#holla {
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
 }
</style>


</head>
<body>

    <div id= "holla">
       <img src="smiley.png">
    <?php
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];
      $from = 'From: webpage'; 
      $to = 'emailaddressblocked'; 
      $subject = 'Hello';
      $human = $_POST['human'];

      $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

      if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
      if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
      echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
      } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
      } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
      }
      }
     ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part of the code shows up? Only part of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this PHP code showing up as regular text (html)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899752/why-is-this-php-code-showing-up-as-regular-text-html)

Comment: this is what shows up:

Comment: this is what shows up Your message has been sent!
'; } else { echo '
Something went wrong, go back and try again!

'; } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') { echo '
You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!

'; } } ?>

Comment: this does look like the same code as the second comment.  same issue.

Comment: You have a misplaced closing brace `}` for your `if()`,remove it from after your `else if` and place it before the `else if`

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part of code:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
}
```

into:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($human == '4') {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
}
```

Earlier in your code you have else and else if together and you repeated the same condition inside if statement and for sure it wasn't what you wanted to do.