# Capture php variable from (Index1.php) To (Index2.html)

Tags: php, html

I try to capture the value of `$app_id` with the `$_POST` method to `Index2.html` with the code below and I can't.

The `php` code in html page don't change the color and that is the signal that the server doesn't work! I'm using Dreamweaver cs6 as editor

Index1.php:

```
$app_id = $_POST["appID"]
```

Index2.html:

```
<label for="appID"><?php $_POST['appID'] ?></label>
```

Comment: unless you've configured your server to treat .html files as a php script, this cannot possibly work. and even if you had, it'd have to be `<?php echo $_POST['appID'] ?>`

Comment: How do you want to use php: `<?php $_POST['appID'] ?>` in a html document? Where is the logic hidden? Also what do you do if the variable is undefined...

Comment: Are you including PHP code inside a HTML file?

Comment: off course that the variable is defined and I have all necessary code I only post one portion of code and the point is that I cant catch the value of that variable in my html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your server configured to run HTML files as PHP files? You're trying to run a PHP code inside a HTML file! You should rename `index2.html` to `index2.php` and run it inside an Apache server, or configure your Apache to run HTML as PHP. Also, `index2` must be the `action` of `index1` form.

**UPDATE**

[How to parse HTML as PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)

Comment: this is not correct .. any file extension **can be** configured in apache to parse it through php .. index.php index.jpg wathever.myextension

Comment: I have xampp as a virtual server

Comment: @abelvf Is it configured to parse PHP code inside HTML files?