# PHP in html not parsing

Tags: php, html

I have a html file and I want to run PHP code to call out an array value within HTML form box but the interpreter doesn't recognize

`<input value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>"/>`

p.s. Not sure if it makes any difference but I am running this on cloud9 with apache (httpd).

Comment: Sounds like PHP is not enabled at the apache module leve.

Comment: You need to have php 5 installed for this to run.

Answer (score 5):

Save your HTML file as a PHP file since HTML files cannot execute php code. For example if your file is named index.html you want to re-save it as index.php once you do that your php code should run.

Answer (score 1):

HTML files does not parse PHP. You need to have a file with .php as extension to run PHP.

PS: Its possible to make HTML file run PHP as well but that requires some extra settings in apache config which is never enabled by default. Reason being a security threat. But If you have a dedicated server which allows playing with apache config then you can achieve this..
have a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)

Comment: That link seems very useful; unfortunately I seem to lack permission to modify httpd.conf and .htaccess seems disabled.  I did email their support to see if they have a workaround. 

Also php5 module is enabled; I can actually run other php code fine but it just doesn't recognize <?php  while inside a http <value>.  I was thinking maybe there was a need to escape that since it is not interpreting <?php as a code tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out that it was actually working all along =/ (i was only looking at the local IDE display within cloud9 but the code was working all along  since it actually required back-end processing and the local IDE won't display that).