# echoing a php variable value in html html and not php file

Tags: php, html

building on from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554081/echoing-a-php-variable-value-in-html-showing-variable-name-and-not-value) it turns out that i have to save the file as a *.php file to display the variable value.

Is there a way to achieve this by keeping the file as a .html? But still achieving the year being displayed in the browser?

here is the code:

```
    <?php
        $year = date("Y");
        echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. X Team</p>";

    ?>
```

So instead of haveing file.php with the above code I would have file.html with the above code but achieving the same thing.

Comment: You need to reconfigure your HTTP server (Apache, IIS?) to process .html files as PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use php use Javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
now = new Date
theYear=now.getYear()
if (theYear < 1900)
theYear=theYear+1900
document.write(theYear)
</script>
```

All html files should allow you to use java script.

Comment: tks, this is me playing with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kdLzL3kt/1/)