# file .htacces AddType not working annymore

Tags: php, apache

Since a few days, my website is no longer working, instead of displaying the site, it downloads the source code(the file is called 'download' without any extension). After some digging it appears to be the .htacces file, the 'AddType application/x-httpd-PHP .html .htm' rule.

When removing, it works fine(when i rename the .html file to .php manually). However, my site relies on this rule, because all my files are called .html and renaming everything to .php isn't really an option.

It has worked fine for months.
The information I know:
Php version : 5.6.38
Web server: apache/2

Comment: this post should help You: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php

Comment: unfortunately, i found that post before i posted my post. Sadly enough the solution isnt there

Comment: It might be configured on apache config level and all .htaccess settings might be ignored. You should contact Your server administrator.

Comment: As suggested in the previous comment, you specifically need `AllowOverride +FileInfo` for `AddType` to work in `.htaccess`.

Comment: This gives me an internal server error with err code 500

Comment: I meant that you need that in your main server config (in your `Directory` directive to be more specific), you cannot use it inside the .htaccess. As @KrzysztofCzerwiński suggested, talk to your server admin and give him the information.

Comment: Ahhhw, now i get it. I just contacted my host and they said that direct admin made it this way, so it would maby have something to do with security. And dont wanna add that line of code or annything. So its nothing on our side. Thank you guys