# AddHandler is not parsing the php in html/htm files

Tags: php, apache

I`ve used this handler in php version 5> . The PHP in all the htm/html was parsed correctly. Since I moved to php 7 this handler stopped working.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Is there any particular reason for that ?

Comment: This might help :https://stackoverflow.com/q/57861812/12232340

Comment: No, it didn't. The same directive works on my local LAMP, so I guess it is something on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

you could try to provide the version as below for 7.0:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .html .htm
```

Or for 7.3:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .html .htm
```