# How can I take a result from a php code into html page

Tags: php, html

My webpage is PHP.
I have a HTML landing page in my subdomain and must stay HTML.
In my subdomain i have a .PHP page and give me room prices per day.
I have include  this code in my HTML page but doesn't work.
 `&euro; <?php getRoomRates('standard');  ?>`
In my official website it works perfect.
I know that .php codes doesn't work in HTML pages.
I have try some solutions from here as .htaccess file but doesn't work.
I am not professional but i try ....

Comment: in order to let the server knows that there are some php content in the page it has to be with a php extension, it is default behaviour, but you can also ask the server to send html pages to php : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php

Comment: You can use ajax for php content

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the file as a .php file and redirect it using RewriteRule. Add this code to your .htaccess file:

```
# if you don't already have it:
RewriteEngine On

# redirect html to php
RewriteRule ^your/public/html/file.html$ path/to/your/php/file.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i tried save the file as .php all page graphics have been dismantled.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, my answer doesn't work. The paths in the .php file must be relative to the public .html file, because the browser doesn't know where the .php file is.

Comment: Maybe i don't understood what i exactly to make. My file is answertest.html. I saved as answertest.php. It is in my subdomain https://www.my.subdomain.gr/answertest.php. Have i to include both pages in ftp html and php? I dont understood how i will make the RewriteRule ^your/public/html/file.html$ path/to/your/php/file.php. The paths in the .php file it is relative to the public .html file

Comment: Add this to your .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^answertest.html$ answertest.php` And no, you don't have to save a file with a .html extension on the server.